# Elixir: Idiomatic way to calculate difference of consecutive elements?

Tags: elixir

I'd like to calculate the difference of consecutive elements in a numeric list, e.g. `input = [1, 2, 3, 5]` should give the output `[-1, -1, -2]`.

I've come up with two ways that seem more or less complicated. Is there a simpler, more idiomatic way to do this?

**Using zip:**

```
Enum.zip(input, Enum.drop(input,1)) 
|> Enum.map(fn {x,y} -> x-y end)
```

**Using scan (way too complicated):**

```
Enum.scan(input, [0, 0], fn x, [_delta, prev] -> [prev-x, x] end) 
|> Enum.map(fn [x, _y] -> x end) 
|> Enum.drop(1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well that is a very specific use-case, so there's no built-in solution that does exactly that, but I think using [`Enum.chunk_every/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/4) is the *most* idiomatic you can be:

> **`chunk_every(enumerable, count, step, leftover \\ [])`**
>
> Returns list of lists containing `count` items each, where each new chunk starts `step` elements into the enumerable.

---

**Example & Explanation:**

```ex
input
|> Enum.chunk_every(2, 1, :discard)
|> Enum.map(fn [x, y] -> x - y end)
```

- The members are grouped into lists of `2` elements each
- Next chunk starts after `1` step from the previous list's starting element
- `:discard` means that it discards the last leftover `[5]` chunk, since we don't need it.
- This returns elements in groups like this: `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5]]`
- Finally calculates the difference for each chunk using `Enum.map`

Comment: This is great because it is more generally useful for doing things with adjacent elements. I was not really expecting a built-in `diff` function.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, everything might be done with pure [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce/3).

```rb
input
|> Enum.reduce({nil, []}, fn
  e, {nil, acc} -> {e, acc}
  e, {prev, acc} -> {e, [prev - e | acc]}
end) # this does already contain the answer btw
|> elem(1)
|> :lists.reverse()
#⇒ [-1, -1, -2]
```

Answer (score 1):

While I like the reduce based version better, using `zip` helps better understanding the problem.

First we make a shifted version of input:

```
[_ | next] = input
```

And then we zip `input` and `next` and calculate the subtracts:

```
input |> Enum.zip(next) |> Enum.map(fn {a, b} -> a - b end)
```

The value of `input |> Enum.zip(next)` part is `[{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}]`. At that stage every item is paired with its next item.